# Babel date_format returning 2016 for 2017 date

Tags: python, python-babel

I'm trying to display the date formatted for the specified language and I'm little surprised to see that:

```
babel.dates.format_date(date(2017,1,1), 'MMM Y')
```

gives the expected value which is:

```
u'Jan 2017'
```

while:

```
babel.dates.format_date(date(2017,1,1), 'MMM Y', locale='fr_FR')
```

gives me:

```
u'janv. 2016'
```

Why is it 2016 not 2017?

Comment: What is your precise question?

Comment: What’s the question?  As to the abbreviated months, According to us poor sots across the pond, `janv.` is the correct french abbreviated month format for January (https://lts.library.cornell.edu/lts/pp/spp/mosabbr#french).

Comment: Yes, but it should be 2017 not 2016 :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `Y` is giving you the week year. You need to use `yyyy` to get what you expect.

See https://github.com/python-babel/babel/issues/138

```
print format_date(date(2017,1,1), 'MMM yyyy')

print format_date(date(2017,1,1), 'MMM yyyy', locale='fr_FR')

Jan 2017
janv. 2017
```

Comment: also see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table